# Where is more information on Heroku labs?

Tags: heroku

We use Sentry, and it wants you to enable a Heroku labs feature.  After doing so, I noticed many others:

```
~> heroku labs -a my-app                
=== User Features me@domain.com
[+] app-overview                         An overview page for an app
[ ] dashboard-enterprise-accounts        Allow users and/or teams to access enterprise account features in Dashboard
[+] dashboard-pb-websockets              allow user to connect to particleboard for eventbus events via websocket [alpha]
[ ] github-enterprise                    Heroku Buttons for GitHub Enterprise
[+] metrics-beta                         App Metrics Beta Features
[ ] metrics-chart-config                 Set order and visibility preferences for your metrics charts
[ ] metrics-data-lag                     Adds an indicator to your graphs when data is still processing, or not available. Prevents graphs from falling off before data is available, or when a data gap occurs.
[ ] metrics-p99-max-response-times       Modifies the Response Time plot to include P99 and Max latency time series.
[ ] metrics-platform-status-events       Display Heroku platform incidents and scheduled maintenance for your application’s region in the Application Metrics Events chart.
[ ] metrics-request-volume               Modifies the Throughput plot to change units from request per minute to requests per second and also display request volume stratified by status code.
[ ] metrics-response-time-summary        Shows summary average statistics for response time over a given time period.
[ ] metrics-seven-day-lookback           Allows you to see data from the past seven days of data on the same chart
[ ] metrics-three-day-lookback           Allows you to see data from the the past two 24-hour periods
[ ] metrics-three-day-lookback-combined  Allows viewing the past three days of data on the same chart
[ ] team-internal-routing                Enables access to Internal Routing in Private Spaces for a team

=== App Features ⬢ my-app
[ ] app-alerting               Allows the creation of alerts for Web Dynos
[ ] go-language-metrics        Display language specific metrics for Go apps
[ ] http-end-to-end-continue   Send 100-continue headers to the backend
[ ] http-shard-header          Turn shard headers on
[ ] log-runtime-metrics        Emit dyno resource usage information into app logs
[ ] no-docker-release          Don't create a release at the end of 'docker push'
[ ] nodejs-language-metrics    Display language specific metrics for Node.js apps
[ ] ruby-language-metrics      Display language specific metrics for Ruby apps
[+] runtime-dyno-metadata      Share dyno metadata in environment variables
[ ] runtime-empty-entrypoint   Force an empty entrypoint when one is not present in the container image
[ ] runtime-heroku-exec        Enable Heroku Exec for all dynos on an app
[ ] runtime-heroku-metrics     Displays language-specific memory metrics.
[ ] runtime-new-layer-extract  Use new layer extraction tool for container image
[ ] runtime-tar-layer-extract  Use tar as the layer extraction tool for container image
[ ] spaces-extra-resolver      causes the container runtime to lookup and inject a single IP from the HEROKU_EXTRA_RESOLVER config var as an extra DNS resolver
[ ] spaces-new-router          Use new dogwood router
[ ] spaces-strict-tls          Drop legacy browser support for strict TLS compliancy requirements
[ ] web-auto-scaling           Allows autoscaling based on a desired latency (p95)
```

[This page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/labs) has a tiny bit of information.  Some options are self-explanatory, but I enabled `app-overview`, for instance, and have not seen anything new.

Is anybody aware of information on the rest of the labs options?